# Confusion in behaviour of onAppear() in sikuli

Tags: observer-pattern, sikuli

```
def stop(event):
    popup("Done")
    event.region.stopObserver()
    pass
wmp = App("C:\\Program Files\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer")
wmp.open()
wait(2)
click(find(Pattern("play_button.png").exact()))
popup("Started Playing")
wait(3)
onAppear(Pattern("stop_button.png").exact(),stop)
observe(FOREVER)
```

In the above code snippet I am try in to play the a mp3 file in windows media player and observing it till the stop button appears, after it appears, it would display the popup message "Done".  When I run this program for first time, the popup message displays for one time, when I run it again, it displays the popup message two times and on the third time, it displays it thrice.  Could someone explain me why is it happening, though I have give only one `popup("Done")` in the code snippet??

Comment: Are you running a script in Sikuli IDE or from command line? Is Windows Media Player window closed after each script run?

Comment: I ran it in Sikuli IDE. No Windows Media Player was not getting closed after each script run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is, that this is some kind of caching problem in the IDE: 
It seems like the default Region is not reset after/before a script is executed, so everytime you run the script, the onAppear listener is added again and this leads to multiple events at the same time.

This is just a guess but if I'm right, you can workaround this by using

```
Region screenRegion = Region.create(Screen(0).x, Screen(0).y, Screen(0).w, Screen(0).h)
screenRegion.onAppear(Pattern("stop_button.png").exact(),stop)
screenRegion.observe(FOREVER)
```

this will create a new Region with every script run and not apply the onAppear listeners to the default Region.

Comment: After creating the region like you stated it:

`region = Region.create(Screen(0).x, Screen(0).y, Screen(0).w, Screen(0).h)`

I have to add the following statement:

`region = Region(region)`

Or it errors:

`[error] onAppear(P(HDR_Expose_3_Batch_Processing_Icon.png) S: 0.99): invalid Region - use r = Region(r) before as workaround
[error] observe(): Nothing to observe (for Jython: region might be invalid)`

Comment: Which version of Sikuli are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the problem in my environment but based on a description I have 2 suggestions:

- Close WMP window after each test run. Perhaps script looks in a loop for all occurences of "stop_button.png". However I would expect that it stops searching immidiately after first occurence is found (http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.onAppear).

OR

- Export script to executable format *skl* and run using command line (http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html). Maybe Sikuli IDE keeps something in its cache (I used to have some issues with it).

Answer (score 0):

1. You should restrict the onAppear listener to a particular region to increase performance
2. You must stop the observer when terminating the program.  `region.stopObserver()`
3. According to Sikuli docs you should use `observe(background=True)` instead of `observe(FOREVER)`